# code coverage - which run covers which code?

Tags: c, gcc, code-coverage, gcov, lcov

The POC: https://gist.github.com/1197309

I would like to determine which of the three runs `./prime`, `./prime 0` and `./prime 1` have covered which code and have it nicely displayed in the HTML report.

Is this possible in a straightforward fashion? How to do it? Other tools are ok, as long as they work on linux with gcc.

Thanks.

Note: I would prefer a working fork of that gist :-) I'm using a "regular" developer linux distribution, so no worries about the tools.

Any other improvements are welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure: Just rename the coverage file after each run, then examine the three files individually and create a merged HTML report.

Or create HTML from the three files and merge the HTML - that might be more simple than writing a parser for the coverage output.

Oh, you meant "built-in" or "simple"? No.